# How is ASP.NET Core able to convert any type to ActionResult<T> return type of controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have simple action in WebApi controller in ASP.NET Core 2.2 that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("test123")]
public ActionResult<string> Test123()
{
    return new OkResult();
}
```

This compiles fine but I am wondering how is it possible that `OkResult` object is converted to `ActionResult<string>`?

These classes have different inheritance chain:
`OkResult -> StatusCodeResult -> ActionResult`
while `ActionResult<TValue>` only implements `IConvertToActionResult`
In other words, `ActionResult<string>` is not base type for `OkResult` class.

If I do that manually and change code to:

```
[HttpGet("test123")]
public ActionResult<string> Test123()
{
    var a = new OkResult();
    var b = a as ActionResult<string>;  // Error CS0039

    return b;
}
```

the code wont compile with the conversion error:

> Error CS0039: Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkResult' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

How is it possible that first code works while the second doesn't? How is return type converted from objects that don't have common base type?

Comment: The first example uses an [implicit cast](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs#L61).

Comment: To support @KirkLarkin statement look at the source code here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f79f2e3b1200f8e672b77583a54e6157e49da9e4/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs#L69

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following two implicit operators from `ActionResult<TValue>`

```
/// <summary>
/// Implictly converts the specified <paramref name="value"/> to an <see cref="ActionResult{TValue}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value to convert.</param>
public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(TValue value)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(value);
}

/// <summary>
/// Implictly converts the specified <paramref name="result"/> to an <see cref="ActionResult{TValue}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="result">The <see cref="ActionResult"/>.</param>
public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(ActionResult result)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(result);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f79f2e3b1200f8e672b77583a54e6157e49da9e4/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs#L69)

Is what allows for the use of multiple return types in the action.

```
[HttpGet("test123")]
public ActionResult<string> Test123() {
    if(someCondition) return "String value"; //<--String
    return Ok(); //<-- OkResult
}
```

When the string is returned the `ActionResult<TValue>(TValue value)` operator is invoked, returning a valid `ActionResult<TValue>` and  vice versa of the other operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example takes advantage of an implicit user-defined type conversion operator, which looks like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs#L61):

```
public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(ActionResult result)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(result);
}
```

Your second example, using `as`, is unable to use the implicit conversion operator as, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as#remarks), it:

> ...performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.