# Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable<T>' to 'ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ienumerable, webapi

I am trying to get a list of entries from database. But I am getting an error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<models.DbModels.GrantProgram>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<models.DbModels.GrantProgram>>' [API]

Please help me. How can I solve this?

**Controller.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>>> GetGrants()
{
  //This is where the error is showing. 
  return await _grants.GetGrants(); 
}
```

**Business layer**

IGrants.cs

```
Task<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>> GetGrants();
```

Grants.cs

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>> GetGrants()
{
    return await _grantRepository.GetGrants(); 
}
```

**Data access layer**

IGrantsRepository.cs

```
Task<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>> GetGrants();
```

GrantsRepository.cs

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>> GetGrants()
{
    return await _context.GrantProgram.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: @The General  Yes, I know that. I wanted to learn three-layer architecture. How can I solve this problem in this scenario?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7981

Comment: I suspect the code you want is something like `return new ActionResult<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>>(await _grants.GetGrants());`

Comment: @mjwills  Thank you so much! My question was closed by someone telling it's a duplicate. But the answer to the question mentioned didn't solve my problem. But your solution worked!

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the code you want is something like

```
return new ActionResult<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>>(await _grants.GetGrants());
```

Why does your existing code not work? Because (as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#actionresultt-type)):

> C# doesn't support implicit cast operators on interfaces.

It suggests:

> Consequently, conversion of the interface to a concrete type is
> necessary to use ActionResult.

which is not strictly speaking true. It is an *option*, yes (e.g. call `ToList`), but it isn't **necessary**. Another option (as I show) is to `new` up `ActionResult` yourself rather than rely on the implicit conversion).

Other reading:

- [ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>> has to return a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742520/actionresultienumerablet-has-to-return-a-listt)
- [How is ASP.NET Core able to convert any type to ActionResult<T> return type of controller actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477600/how-is-asp-net-core-able-to-convert-any-type-to-actionresultt-return-type-of-c)

Comment: With C# 9.0 [Target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new), your answer can now be simplified to `return new(await _grants.GetGrants());`.

Answer (score 3):

since you are using ActionResult consider to use this

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>>> GetGrants()
{
 
  return Ok ( await _grants.GetGrants() ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docs ([Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types), published in February 2022), consider only using ActionResult as the return type if your method could return different ActionResults. Since this example only has one return path, you could instead use simpler code that defines a specific type as the return value. Here is what your code would look like with this change:

**Controller.cs**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GrantProgram>> GetGrants()
{
  //This is where the error is showing. 
  return await _grants.GetGrants(); 
}
```